# When using roslibjs, getting value of some params returns empty

Tags: ros, parameter, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to programmatically fetch params from my ROS instance using roslibjs. When fetching some params, the value returns successfully, however with other params the value returned is empty.

Here is a snippet of the code in question:

```
var bridge = new ROSLIB.Ros();
bridge.on('connection', onConnect);
bridge.on('error', onError);
bridge.connect('my-ros-server');

...

var param = new ROSLIB.Param({
    ros: bridge,
    name: name
});

param.get(function(value) {
    console.log(value.toString());
});
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62317/when-using-roslibjs,-getting-value-of-some-params-returns-empty./) by [Jamison](https://answers.ros.org/users/4838/jamison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-05-07**:
It would be helpful if you could also post examples of some parameters that work and some that fail.  For example, using rosparam dump param_name to show the type/value of each parameter.

**Comment by [Jamison](https://answers.ros.org/users/4838/jamison/) on 2013-05-07**:
I'll give it my best shot! ros_version returns "fuerte". "rrHardwareStatus4Enable", my own custom parameter, returns blank. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hi all, I wanted to post the answer to my question! I figured it out!**

To get the value of a param from ROS using roslibjs, you must supply the **full parameter name, *not a truncated version*!**

My application was putting all of the params that ROS reported into a collapsible/expandable tree, and was stripping the /blah/ prefix from params like /blah/blahparam.

To reiterate, to get the value of a param from ROS, you must specify /blah/blahparam, not just blahparam.

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [Jamison](https://answers.ros.org/users/4838/jamison/) with karma: 26 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was an issue with roslibjs r5 and earlier: https://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs/issues/37

r6 was pushed today with fixes and posted to the CDN as well.

If this still isn't working, verify the parameter is actually set using `rosparam get <param_name>` in the console.

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1